# Camera Location ( Projective Geometry - Computer Vision)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, computer-vision

I want to find the location of a camera in 'world coordinates' based on projective geometry.
My source of theory is the book [Multiple View geometry in Computer Vision](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf), as well as 
[A Flexible New Technique for Camera
Calibration](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr98-71.pdf) .

I performed a camera calibration to get the intrinsic parameters, K
and took a picture from a rectangle Pattern (4 points) in the wall to get the projections of the point set in the image. So now I have:

- Intrinsic parameter matrix K of my camera.
- Calibrated real world points in the wall X1..X4
- Measured points x1..x4 (u,v) in the image.
- Rotation matrix of the camera (in fact the camera is parallel to the wall).

My question is how should I find C having points and projected points X,x,K,R: 
with the projection matrix below I can't get the z component of C.

$$
    x = K R\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  I&-C
\end{array}
\right] X
$$

[image: Pinhole camera geometry]

**EDIT**
Based on Peter Sheldrick comment below I came to a potential solution to the equation $$x = P X$$ and I would like to know if is consistent.

$$ x = P\cdot X \\x^T = X^T \cdot P^T \\ (X\cdot X^T)^{-1}\cdot X \cdot x^T = P^T \\ P = x\cdot X^T\cdot (X\cdot X^T)^{-T} $$

Comment: Ingenious solution in your answer. Thanks @PeterSheldrick

Comment: @PeterSheldrick, please have a look at my EDIT to see if you find consistent  to solve the projective equation.

Comment: X and x are in this case matrices with the homogeneous vectors. So X is 4x4 and x is 3x4. I tested and is feasible operation.